# Rewrite Rule to make clean home page url

Tags: url, url-rewriting, clean-urls, rule

i need to rewrite my homepage.

in navigation bar i want to see http://domain.com/ which is created from real page http://domain.com/abc

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your apache conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /$ http://domain.com/abc [QSA,L,P]
```